# Encryption of session in MultipeerConnectivity framework for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, multipeer-connectivity

I am working on iOS multipeer framework and I am pretty happy with it. I am sharing some senstive data so have to do the encryption. 
When we create the session we get three options:

```
self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myPeerID
                              securityIdentity:nil 
                          encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionRequired];
```

1. `MCEncryptionNone`
2. `MCEncryptionOptional`
3. `MCEncryptionRequired`

   I read the Apple guide but couldn't find much info about it. If I pass `MCEncryptionRequired`, does someone know what kind of encryption it does?
   Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find out this information?  I am trying to track this down to determine of the security the framework provides is sufficient for my application

Answer (score 4):

Alban Diquet analysed the framework's communications and documented his results in this [BlackHat presentation](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Diquet-It-Just-Networks-The-Truth-About-iOS-7s-Multipeer-Connectivity-Framework.pdf). From page 58:

*MCEncryptionRequired With Authentication*:

- DTLS with mutual authentication:
- Each peer sends their certificate and validate the other side’s certificate
- RSA & EC-DSA TLS Cipher Suites
- 30 cipher suites supported in total including PFS cipher suites.!
- In practice, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 is always negotiated, which doesn’t provide PFS

From page 61:

*MCEncryptionRequired Without Authentication*:

- DTLS with Anonymous TLS Cipher Suites No certificates exchanged
- “Anon" AES TLS cipher suites:

  - TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
  - TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
  - TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
  - TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256